# Getting a document from liferay repository

Tags: repository, liferay, liferay-6, jackrabbit, document-management

We've setup liferay to use JackRabbit as its document repository. Now what I'm trying to do is retrieve an specific document, and all I know about it is it's `name`, and sometimes the name of the `folder` it may be located in.

I know `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil` allows me to retrieve said document but requires me to have it's `id` before handing it over. My question is, how can I get the `id` of the file I'm looking for if all I have is the file `name` and it's `location`?

Comment: Only file name or its folder name will not work for it. You need to have both the information to get Document. Also you will be needing groupId for it.[if you store documents at Global scope then groupId could be themeDispay.getCompanyGroupId()]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code snippet could help you,

```
FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(repositoryId, CREATED_FOLDER_ID, fileName);
```

In above, you have pass repositoryId could be equivalent to groupId which you can get it from themedisplay.getGroupId(), your folderId and fileName

you can get folderId by below code,

```
        long FOLDER_ID = 0;
        long repositoryId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
        long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
        List<Folder> lFolder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolders(repositoryId, parentFolderId);
        for (Folder folder : lFolder)
        {
            if (folder.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(FOLDER_NAME))
            {
                FOLDER_ID = folder.getFolderId();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Please let me know if it helps